# What would cause a CLI utility to ignore arguments except when invoked directly?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, macos

Okay, so this just happened:

```
iMac:bin nreilingh$ tree --version
.
|____tree
iMac:bin nreilingh$ which tree
/usr/local/bin/tree
iMac:bin nreilingh$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/tree
lrwxr-xr-x  1 nreilingh  admin  29 Oct 14 22:02 /usr/local/bin/tree -> ../Cellar/tree/1.7.0/bin/tree
iMac:bin nreilingh$ pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/tree/1.7.0/bin
iMac:bin nreilingh$ ./tree --version
tree v1.7.0 (c) 1996 - 2014 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher, Florian Sesser, Kyosuke Tokoro
```

I installed tree via homebrew, and whenever I invoke it, it ignores command line arguments. When I execute the binary directly, it doesn't. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `tree` is defined as a function or alias in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` file?

Check output of `\tree --version`

Comment: Or try `command tree --version`

Comment: holy crap, you're right. I had a one-liner function for tree in my `.profile`